# Plural Function not found for locale

Tags: jhipster

After upgrading to JHipster 2.19 from the 2.18 version, I notice that another language other than English version isn't working properly. After clicking on a button, for example, nothing happens. On the Google Chrome, I see the following error message

```
Plural Function not found for locale: zh-cn
```

I have a look at [Angular Translate document](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization) and can't tell what is wrong after comparing the English version and zh version all json files under i18n directory.

I don't know whether it is due to something I didn't do properly during the upgrading process or it is a bug in 2.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you see a line like this in your index.html?

```
<script src="bower_components/messageformat/locale/zh-cn.js"></script>
```

Normally it should have been done by grunt/gulp, you could try to run `grunt build`

Comment: Thanks for your input when my head hits a wall for this problem. There was not the line in my index.html file, none any other zh javascript files. However, There isn't a zh-cn.js under the directory, but zh.js. So, I use <script src="bower_components/messageformat/locale/zh.js"></script> instead. Based on my test so far, it works.